# Masking output of object detection (YOLO) on the corresponding images processed by the object segmentation model (U-net)

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, image-segmentation, roi

I used UNET to segment cracks on the road, and used YOLO to detect them. images were processed through the proposed YOLO and U-net models individually and the detected objects in the proposed yolo model image should be masked on the corresponding images processed by the U-net model to find the ration of white/black pixels in the bounding boxes. How can I do this masking?
Thanks in advance!

[image: UNET output]

[image: YOLO output]

Comment: if you didnt change the image sizes, just use the yolo box positions on your UNet output image?!?

Comment: YOLO outputs the corners of the rectangle, so you should be able to use these to crop the image. See the `YOLO Object Detection with OpenCV` section [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/).

Comment: @Barak Itkin
So,as the first step I need to crop rectangles from the UNET outputs with the same coordinates as the YOLO output bounding boxes.
what is the next step? How can I measure the number of white pixels in each bonding box?

Comment: @Micka
No I didnt change the image size

Comment: if pixels are in the full range of 0 to 255 you have to find a threshold first. Afterwards you can use cv2.countNonZero to get the number of pixels which are not zero.